# Why does Zeppelin 0.6.2 notebook fail with "The input line is too long" with Spark 2.0 on Windows?

Tags: windows, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

Am running Zeppelin 0.6.2 in windows with Spark 2.0

```
SPARK_HOME=C:\Users\anbarasu.r\Desktop\Archive\spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.6
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512m;support was removed in 8.0
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/anbarasu.r/Desktop/Archive/zeppelin-0.6.2-bin-all/zeppelin 0.6.2-bin-all/lib/slf4j-log4j12         1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/anbarasu.r/Desktop/Archive/zeppelin-0.6.2-bin-all/zeppelin-0.6.2-bin-all/lib/zeppelin-interpreter-0.6.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Nov 19, 2016 1:48:15 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:  org.apache.zeppelin.rest
Nov 19, 2016 1:48:15 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
INFO: Root resource classes found:
class org.apache.zeppelin.rest.ZeppelinRestApi
class org.apache.zeppelin.rest.ConfigurationsRestApi
class org.apache.zeppelin.rest.CredentialRestApi
class org.apache.zeppelin.rest.NotebookRestApi
class org.apache.zeppelin.rest.LoginRestApi
class org.apache.zeppelin.rest.InterpreterRestApi
class org.apache.zeppelin.rest.SecurityRestApi`
Nov 19, 2016 1:48:15 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig init
INFO: No provider classes found.
Nov 19, 2016 1:48:15 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.13 06/29/2012 05:14 PM'
Nov 19, 2016 1:48:18 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors processErrorMessages
WARNING: The following warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
WARNING: A HTTP GET method, public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.apache.zeppelin.rest.InterpreterRestApi.listInterpreter(java.lang.String), should not consume any entity.
WARNING: A sub-resource method, public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.apache.zeppelin.rest.NotebookRestApi.createNote(java.lang.String) throws java.io.IOException, with URI template, "/", is treated as a resource method
WARNING: A sub-resource method, public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.apache.zeppelin.rest.NotebookRestApi.getNotebookList() throws java.io.IOException, with URI template, "/", is treated as a resource method
SPARK_HOME=C:\Users\anbarasu.r\Desktop\Archive\spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.6
The input line is too long.
```

The error

> The input line is too long

appears in the command line when I run any command on the notebook.

But Zeppelin 0.6.2 work perfectly with Spark 1.6.2

Please suggest a way to make Zeppelin 0.6.2 work with Spark 2.0.0.

Comment: Databricks Community Edition supports the same set of Spark versions as non-community Databricks deployments, including Spark 2.0.0+.

Comment: I made a virtual box Ubuntu 16.4 and use that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for the error is among the "niceties" that make people "love" Windows so much :) It used to have a very poor command line support.

(I said *"used to have"* as things have changed recently with bash and Docker support)

I strongly suggest installing Spark and Zeppelin in directories with shorter paths, say:

1. `c:\spark` for Apache Spark
2. `c:\zeppelin` for Apache Zeppelin

And start over.

Moreover, you don't have to install Spark separately to use Zeppelin as it comes with Spark pre-installed/bundled. That gives you less to worry, i.e. no need for `SPARK_HOME`.

You've got them as follows:

1. `C:\Users\anbarasu.r\Desktop\Archive\spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.6` for Apache Spark
2. `C:/Users/anbarasu.r/Desktop/Archive/zeppelin-0.6.2-bin-all/zeppelin-0.6.2-bin-all` for Apache Zepplin

which (as I've just experienced) takes too much space out of the available space for paths on Windows.